# include an arrow in list with content and move over the li content

Tags: html, css

I want to move over the content of my li's.

I included arrows before my li's:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "\25ba\00a0";
}
```

It looks really bad:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/Vj8dd/293/

Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve??

Comment: do you want the <li> content move in single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place icons with `position: absolute`.

Add some left indent on list item so that it always start from a few pixel ahead and text align correctly after wrapping.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

li:before {
  content: "\25ba\00a0";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div style="max-width:200px;">
    <ul>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>basdasdasfs fgsdfgrfgfg fgf gdf g sdfgd fgdf fg fg r</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```